# Is there a css debugging tool to test an entire stylesheet for conflicts?

Tags: css

I created a stylesheet for jquery mobile using the [ThemeRoller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/) tool. It looks really great on the ThemeRoller page. In my mobile app... not so good. I think there must be some conflicts in definitions between my stylesheet and the jquery stylesheets.

Rails layout file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery_mob_theme.min", "jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min", "stylin.mobile" %>
```

For those of you not familiar with rails it is rendered:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery_mob_theme.min.css?1338304118" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css?1338312435" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/stylin.mobile.css?1337894014" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Is the only way to deal with this to wade through thousands of lines of css to look for conflicts? Is there a css debugging tool that will detect that in a stylesheet? I could change the jquery file names to scss and then roll them into one stylesheet. I am familiar with Firebug and Web inspector which check styles on one page. That wouldn't help... right?

Thanks.

Comment: *"In my mobile app... not so good."* - That's not very informative. Please elaborate.

Comment: First try putting your css first so it can will over right yours.

Comment: The standard way of dealing with this sort of issue is to pick one element and then check what styles are applied to it (via the browser's dev tools). You can then compare that with the same element on the ThemeRoller page, in order to determine which additional styles are applied on your page...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, the colors are not coming out the same probably because there are conflicting style definitions for the same elements or classes.

Comment: @corymathews, thanks... i tried that with no difference in the rendering.

Comment: @Jay Well, select the element in question with the dev tools and check which color is applied and where it's coming from (which style sheet)...

Comment: @corymathews, Hey... you were right. I did rearrange the order but didn't get it quite right. I tried stylin.mobile, jquery_mob_theme.min, jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min. I just rearranged them again to stylin.mobile, jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min, jquery_mob_theme.min and it all works. If you put this as an answer then I'll mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your stylin Stylesheets matters for what gets overridden. Make sure your style sheet is before both of the jQuery style sheets.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you, All of css is based on inheritance so there is no automated way of knowing of a conflict or if an object has just overriden the styling of a parent. I think the best bet is to force rails to show the mobile version of the site on a desktop pc and then you can use the Google chrome inspector. It will show you all styles applied to a specific object. It only shows relevant styles with line numbers in the stylesheet so you aren't stuck wading through css. You can also edit it in chrome to see what your changes will look like before you change your stylesheet.

Comment: Didn't know about the editing feature... that will be very helpful. I'll let you know if it helps me solve the overwrite problem.

Comment: i found user agent switcher for Chrome here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en-US&gl=US. When i select mobile user agents the mobile version is not coming up. Do you have a link on the extension that you use with Chrome?

Comment: Hmm, if the user agent switcher is not working, you will have to force rails to show the mobile version via hard coding it.

Answer (score 2):

Firebug (an extension for Firefox) can show all styles applied to any given element, as well as which styles are overridden by other styles.  You would have to view your mobile site from a desktop browser, but this can be done in Firefox by changing the useragent to match that of a mobile device (iPod, Android, etc.)

If you plan on using webkit on your site, Firefox is not a great choice as it does not render webkit css styles.  An alternative is to use Safari and its development tools (which can be activated in the options menu).

If you need to debug from an actual mobile device, there aren't many options.  If you can get Opera mobile onto the device, it comes with a decent debugger called Dragonfly.

Comment: You may have started writing this before I edited my post to mention Firebug and Web Inspector. I'll go back to them again to see if I missed something. Dragonfly... that is new to me. I will check that as well. Thank you.